# What's the right behavior when auto meets polymorphism and virtual function?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

```
class B {
    public:
    virtual void f(){
        printf("B\n");
    }
};
class D : public B { 
    public:
    void f() {
        printf("D\n");
    }
};

int main(void)  
{  
    B* d = new D();
    d->f();
    auto b = *d; 
    b.f();
}
```

for `d->f();`, the output is `D`. this is right.
But for `b.f();`, the output is `B`. **Is this right?**

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to _override_ your virtual function.

Comment: `auto` type deduction and for that matter template type deduction also works on compile time /static type not on its runtime type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is this right?

It's right, the type is deduced at compile time. [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto#Explanation) uses the same rules of [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts) for type deduction, based on the *static* type, dynamic polymorphism won't be considered.

For this case, the type of `d` is `B*`, then type of `*d` is `B`, so the type of `b` is just `B`. Then `*d` will be [slicing copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) to `b`, for `b.f()` `B::f()` should be invoked.

The code is equivalent to the following which might be clearer.

```
B b = *d;
b.f();
```

Comment: However, please note that if it were `auto & b = *d;` (or `auto && b = *d;` ) , then `b.f()` would have invoked the overridden f() in the derived class.